# CatBoostError for Unknown class name

Tags: python-3.x, catboost, catboostregressor

When I run the code below, the following error appears:

```
CatBoostError: c:/goagent/pipelines/buildmaster/catboost.git/catboost/libs/target/target_converter.cpp:64: Unknown class name: "219.9033"
```

My Code:

```
model=CatBoostRegressor(iterations=1000, 
                         depth=5,
                         learning_rate=0.03,
                         loss_function='RMSE',
                         eval_metric='AUC',
                         l2_leaf_reg=10,
                         metric_period=50,
                         thread_count=32,
                         random_seed=42)
```

Catboost version: 0.13
Python version: 3.7

Comment: Would you share more code snippet to show what are you doing and if possible, enough to reproduce the error? And, the full error trace?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that kind of error in **CatBoostClassifier**. The likely reason is that your eval_set has a y value that the train set doesn't have. Look at [**this post**](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/773) for clues.